# using datepicker on <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I want to add datepicker on  but it should have been in HIDE state. on click of div it should show datepicker. Just like on input tag.
I have tried using Button Text and Icon to show it but was not able to display it without input field.

Comment: It would help to see the code you are trying out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="control">Click for calendar</div>
<div id='dp'></div>
```

JS/Jquery:

```
var cal = $('#dp').datepicker();
cal.hide();
$('#control').on('click', function() {
    if (cal.is(':hidden')) {
        cal.show();
    } else {
        cal.hide();
    }
});​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aztechy/dpAWV/

Comment: This doesn't really work. It shows the datepicker inline, rather than overlaid over the page next to the input box.